# Passing information from one view controller to another in XCode using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios9, xcode7

To pass information from one view controller to another, I have been using an integer. I declared this integer in one header file, and then set the value of this integer in various .m files through if-then statements. (If the user chooses a certain option, set the value to 1, of another options, set the value to 2.) Based on the current value of the integer, all .m files should know what option the user selected and act accordingly.

This has worked fine until XCode 7. Now I am getting the error "18 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64" because I used the integer in more than one .m file.

Any suggestions on an alternate way to pass information between view controllers... or how to maintain my current method but get rid of the error... would be greatly appreciated.

Here is some of the code:
    #import 
    int questionTypeInt;
    int iPadInt;
    int rotationInt;
    int iPhoneRotationInt;
    @interface QuestionTypeViewController
...
This is my .h file. Then in the .m file for a different view controller:
    #import "QuestionTypeViewController.h"

Interface left out for space

```
@implementation TermsAndPoliciesViewController
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (iPadInt==0) {
        self.view=self.iPhoneTermsView;
    } else {
        if (rotationInt=90) {
            self.view=self.iPadLandscapeTermsView;
    } else     self.view=self.iPadPortraitTermsView;
    }
```

I use global variables for lots of other things, but they all give me the error.

Comment: Post some of your code.

Comment: Thanks, just added some. It doesn't seem to be formatted correctly on the website -- sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess here since we don't have your code.

It sounds like you just made global variables (not in in the @implementation of a class).

If so, they need to have different names if you want them to be different and available outside of the .m.  If you want them to represent the same thing, them make one new .m and .h and declare and define it just once.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just to clarify, I successfully used global variables in a previous project and just copied and pasted the major portion of the code from that successful project... but now it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

There's a method in all UIViewControllers called "prepareForSegue", this method let's you send information to the next view controller you're gonna push like this...

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    UIViewController *viewControllerYouWantToMoveOn = segue.destinationViewController;
    viewControllerYouWantToMoveOn.info = self.info;
}
```

Where "info" it's the property that carries the passed data

According to Apple...

> Because segues can be triggered from multiple sources, you can use the information in the segue and sender parameters to disambiguate between different logical paths in your app. For example, if the segue originated from a table view, the sender parameter would identify the table view cell that the user tapped. You could then use that information to set the data on the destination view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Without more info, I see easy two options:

1. Make a property on your app delegate.  This is frowned upon, and I would avoid this if possible.  But...it would work.
2. Make a singleton class that all your view controllers can access.  Because it's a singleton, all your view controllers (and anything else) would be interacting with just one instance.